# Any suggestion for a DFT software package for a beginner?

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, soft-question, software, density-functional-theory

I would like to do start doing some basic calculations using DFT. I am interested in solid state physics of strongly correlated materials in 3d or 2d. I prefer free software (no license) which is easy to use. I am interested in DFT as a tool to calculate properties of materials, and I am not interested in learning the details of DFT (at least not now) and also I am not interested in software developing. I have a background in solid state physics. I was thinking about ABINIT, JDFTx, or Quantum Espresso, or any other free/easy to use package. Any suggestion?

Comment: You might be more likely to get a good answer to this at the [Matter Modeling stack](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks. I did not know about it.